# ember render hbs swallowing thrown error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit

I have a simple component integration test:

```
test('it throws error my-custom-input is called', function(assert) {
    assert.throws(() => {
        this.render(hbs`{{my-custom-input}}`);
    }, /my-custom-input component error/, 'Error must have been thrown');
});
```

Source code of component.js is like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        throw 'my-custom-input component error';
    }
}
```

While my ember-cli version was 2.3.0, the test was passing. However, after I've updated my ember-cli version to 2.11.1, the test did not pass. The error was:

```
    actual: >
        false
    expected: >
        true
```

Why does ember render start to swallow the thrown exception?

Comment: I prepared a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/23b50ad0f6a793b117451fa69fc0dd52) to illustrate the case; but surprisingly it works in twiddle. However; when I created a brand new ember application; the test fails as described in the original question. Please check out [project repository](https://github.com/feanor07/ember-component-init-error-swallowed) simply to see the case. I hope someone will benefit from these findings to provide a solution.

Comment: I've filled [an issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15013) in ember.js about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I am not quite sure why Ember community decided to break the test explained; but here is the fix if anyone needs it.

You need to install [ember-qunit-assert-helpers](https://github.com/workmanw/ember-qunit-assert-helpers) via

```
ember install ember-qunit-assert-helpers
```

You need to change your code that `throws` an exception to `Ember.assert` and in your test class you just need to use `assert.expectAssertion` instead of `assert.throws`.

The answer is provided from the github issue at the following [address](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-qunit/issues/256).

Comment: Also, the [original pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/14898) contains a great deal of relevant discussion, and [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15013) contains a [twiddle reproduction](https://ember-twiddle.com/47c4cfbb571ac3fa83ab912f605ebc6a?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=tests.integration.components.i-throw-test.js%2C) and work-around.